# Java Script MVC steal/buildjs - remove empty .js files

Tags: javascript, lint, javascriptmvc, envjs

When I try to do build with steal/buildjs of Javascript MVC, envJS silently fail to compress and check JavaScript files for errors.

I read documentation for envJS and found there that if in some case you try to build empty .js files envJS will fail.

Obviously it is in my case, and later I founded some of empty .js files.

I need a way to add checking for empty .js and .ejs files before build.

What would be the most efficient way to do check for empty .js and .ejs when running steal/buildjs?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [find](https://superuser.com/questions/266200/find-and-remove-all-empty-files):

```
find . -type f \( -name *.js -o -name *.ejs \) -size 0 -print
```

Change `-print` to `-delete` when you're sure.